# Grep outputting strange characters using -A and -B flags for fastq analysis

Tags: bash, fastq, sequencing

I have a file that looks like this:

```
@HISEQ:331:C85AMANXX:8:1101:16636:1980 1:N:0:ATCACGAC
NTCTATAAACTCTTCATGCCAGTTCCCTGTCTCATCAGATAGATTCTGAGGCCTCTAGGCATCAGCCGGATATCCCTAAGGACAGTGTTGGAGGAACTGCTGAGTGGATTCATGGTCAACTACCAA
+
#<<BBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@HISEQ:331:C85AMANXX:8:1101:2337:2047 1:N:0:ATCACGAC
CTGTGAAAACTCTTCATGCCAGTTCCCTGTCTCATCAGATAGATTCTGAGGCCTCTAGGCATCAGCCGGATATCCCTAAGGACAGTGTTGGAGGAACTGCTGAGTGGATTCATGGTCAACTACCAA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFF<FF<BFFFF<FFFFBFFFBFFFFF<B
```

I am using the following grep command:

```
grep -B 1 -A 2 'AGGCATCAGCCGGA' file.fastq | head > out.fastq
```

And the output looks like this where you can see that on lines 5 and 10 that two dashes are output and I would not like it to be so:

```
@HISEQ:331:C85AMANXX:8:1101:16636:1980 1:N:0:ATCACGAC
NTCTATAAACTCTTCATGCCAGTTCCCTGTCTCATCAGATAGATTCTGAGGCCTCTAGGCATCAGCCGGATATCCCTAAGGACAGTGTTGGAGGAACTGCTGAGTGGATTCATGGTCAACTACCAA
+
#<<BBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
--
@HISEQ:331:C85AMANXX:8:1101:2337:2047 1:N:0:ATCACGAC
CTGTGAAAACTCTTCATGCCAGTTCCCTGTCTCATCAGATAGATTCTGAGGCCTCTAGGCATCAGCCGGATATCCCTAAGGACAGTGTTGGAGGAACTGCTGAGTGGATTCATGGTCAACTACCAA
+
BBBBBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFF<FF<BFFFF<FFFFBFFFBFFFFF<B
--
```

Is there a way to output without the dashes on lines 5 and 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `grep` separates context groups by the separator `--`. There may be more than one match in one block so the amount of lines is not constant. The separator will show where the blocks begin and end.

You can add the option `--no-group-separator` to suppress this functionality, if available on your version of `grep`.

Comment: An improvement to this answer would be to explain *why* that's necessary and what it is in the output in the first place. (Yes, the man page for that option covers it but that's not *right here*.) Also, if that option is relatively new (or even just GNU only) an alternative would be good (though the other answers have that covered too).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `grep -v`:

```
grep -B 1 -A 2 'AGGCATCAGCCGGA' file.fastq |
grep -v -- '^--' |
head > out.fastq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pipe to sed :

```
grep -B 1 -A 2 'AGGCATCAGCCGGA' file.fastq | head | sed '/^--$/d'> out.fastq
```